# Could not compile initialization script

Tags: java, gradle, discord4j

So I made a program on my pc that is connected with a discord API using discord4j. On my pc it works just fint, but if I download the project and use it on my laptop I get a weird error in my MacroTester_main__2.gradle. Now the weird thing is, that the path it has a problem with is correct.

does anybody have any idea how to go about this problem and what the solution would be?
Deleting the cache does not solve this issue.

Run the program, it should just run without issue.

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DljRK.png)

Run environment is Intellij.

Gradle version: gradle-7.5.1

discord4j version: 3.2.3

logBack version: 1.2.12

Comment: Hi Double, to provide some answers, more information about the problem would be necessary - error message, environment, code / configuration? We're not extras, sorry

Comment: @yahorbarkouski I hope the information I have added is enough to get a clearer Image of my problem. If not please let me know so I can improve my post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Apparently, it was an issue with my implementation that didn't want to work on my pc. What I did was in my `build.gradle` added another id called application and a section called application in that section you need to define the main class and from there you can run the application in the gradle menu under tasks and application 'run'

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

application {
    mainClass = 'Main'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation 'com.discord4j:discord4j-core:3.2.3'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.12'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image: gradle menu 'run']